# Need help debugging my for loop nested in an if statement nested in a while loop, trying to find out why my list is not being appended to

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import requests

def get_url(*args):
    matched_index =[]
    url_site = []
    
    for a in args:
        city_country_match = False
        city_country = a.replace(" ","-")
        sitemap_index = 5
        sitemap_index_max = 255

    
        while not city_country_match:
            res = requests.get(f'https://weatherspark.com/sitemap-    {sitemap_index}.xml')
            soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,"xml")
            if city_country in res.text:         #is city/country within the     sitemap.xml page?
                city_country_match = True        #ends while loop
                
                for loc in soup.select('loc'):
                    text = loc.text
                    if 'Average-Weather-in-' in text and 'Year-Round' in text     and city_country in text:
                        url_site.append(text)      #***WHY DOES THIS NOT APPEND? *** 
                    
            
                print(f'Found {a} on page {sitemap_index}')
                matched_index.append(sitemap_index)
                url_site.append(text)
            
                time.sleep(1.5)
            else:
                sitemap_index = sitemap_index + 1
                if sitemap_index == sitemap_index_max:
                    print(f"Did not find {city_country}")
            
    return matched_index
    return url_site

get_url("Austin Texas United States, "Calgary Canada")
```

Actual Result:

Found Austin Texas United States on page 20

Found Calgary Canada on page 9

Output: [20,9]

Expected Result is it would have also included in the output:

["https://weatherspark.com/y/8004/Average-Weather-in-Austin-Texas-United-States-Year-Round", "https://weatherspark.com/y/2349/Average-Weather-in-Calgary-Canada-Year-Round"]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your script won't get to the ```return url_list``` as it would've have returned already in the previous line.

Comment: Please also include your sample input, your expected output and the actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to return with:

```
return matched_index, url_site
```

The reason your code will not work currently is because you have two return statements, which means the second return url_site will never be reached.